# jQuery - removeClass() applied to all classes except one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the class `.active` from all the anchors except the `<a>` of child number 2; I don't know why this is not working.

```js
/*Remove ".active" from all the anchors except child number 2 */
$("#list li:not(li:nth-child(2) a)").removeClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<style>
  .active {
    color: red;
  }
</style>


<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector was written wrongly, I'm assuming this was a typo resulting from a later edit of the selector, given the misplaced `)` character. So, rather than:

```
$("#list li:not(li:nth-child(2) a)").removeClass("active");
```

Instead use:

```
$("#list li:not(li:nth-child(2)) a").removeClass("active");
```

Your original selector was looking for an `<li>` element that was not the second-child of its parent and, also, was not an `<a>` element; this is true for all `<li>` elements.

```js
/*Remove ".active" from all the anchors except child number 2 */
$("#list li:not(li:nth-child(2)) a").removeClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<style>
  .active {
    color: red;
  }
</style>


<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You selector is wrong. You should use `#list li a:not(li:nth-child(2) a)` instead.

```js
$("#list li a:not(li:nth-child(2) a)").removeClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
  .active {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, seems like i forgot the anchor tag before the :not, i thought i needed only to put everything between the :not() brackets to give me the opposite, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is better to read:

```js
$("#list li a").not('#list li:nth-child(2) a').removeClass("active");
```

```css
.active{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```